# Не могу открыть папку с vue проектом на macOS

Tags: vue.js, macos, vue3

создал проект vue, он запускается всё отлично. При переходе в Finder я жму на папку и он пишет что "Вы не можете открыть программу «mneclo», так как она повреждена или не содержит необходимых компонентов." Кто поможет пофиксить, буду благодарен.
[image: При открытии пишет вот это]

Comment: Очевидно, что это не проблема, связанная с vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Пересоздать проект - решило проблему.

```
vue create app
cd app
npm I
npm run serve
```